# In the PMTA config should max-msg-rate exceed backoff-max-msg-rate?

Tags: email

Not sure if anyone here is running PMTA

But the <damain *> contains the following lines:

'''
max-msg-rate 1000/h
backoff-max-msg-rate 6000/h
'''

Seems to me that the backoff rate ought to be
lower than the standard rate?

What do you think?